# Unable to install setuptools on mac osx - bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, macos, installation, setuptools, easy-install

I have been trying to install setuptools to get easy_install.

I'm doing the following to install:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Installing Setuptools
running install
Checking .pth file support in /lib/python2.7/site-packages/
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations
```

What can I do to fix this? Why is it checking in `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` when my PYTHONPATH is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`??

```
which python
```

output : `/usr/local/bin/python`

echo $PYTHONPATH

output : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

```
echo $PATH
```

output : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Please help!! I've been searching the internet but haven't able to solve this.

I'm using Mac osx Sierra by the way.

UPDATE:

I even downloaded the zip from: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools`

uzipped the folder and did cd into it. Then I ran :

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

This gave me the same above error!!

Comment: The file you are fetching contains the following comment: *"This method is DEPRECATED. Check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more details."*

Comment: @tripleee I tried downloading it from the python index package page as well but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Most probably you have installed python via Homebrew that interferes with your system python installation. Which one do you want to use as the default one? Also, `easy_install` is available with the system python, as well as `setuptools==18.1`.

Comment: I want to use the one I've installed as default python. Is there a way to get setuptools in that? @hoefling

Comment: The best thing for you would be to leave the preinstalled `setuptools==18.1` alone (otherwise you risk breaking your system) and install `setuptools` as user: `pip install setuptools --user --upgrade`. Check you use the correct version now: `python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptoolsion__)"` should output `38.2.4`.

Comment: @hoefling Okay when I do pip install setuptools --user --upgrade, I get the following error: from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: @hoefling File "/usr/local/bin/pip2", line 6, in <module> from pkg_resources import load_entry_point ImportError: No module named pkg_resources This is the entire error. Why is it going to bin? Shouldn't it be going to lib?

Comment: Oops, sorry - didn't read carefully enough. I see now that you are using the brewed python2 as the default one - never touching brewed pythons myself, too fragile and requires too much dancing around it to work properly so I won't be able to help you.